# Cannot detect error in the following jdbc code 

Tags: java, database, jdbc, prepared-statement

replacing it with

```
package p1;



import java.sql.*;

public class jdbcDemo

{

    public static void main(String args[])
    { int id = 0;
    try
    { Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
       Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:loginDSN");
       Connection con1 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:loginDSN");
      Statement stat = con.createStatement();
      System.out.println("got connection");
      ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery("Select max(UID) from mytable");
      while(rs.next())
      { id=rs.getInt(1);
      }
      id++;
      System.out.println(id);
      PreparedStatement ps = con1.prepareStatement("Insert into mytable(UID,Username,Password) values(?,?,?)");
      ps.setInt(1,id);
      ps.setString(2,"abhi");
      ps.setString(3,"bindra");


     ps.executeUpdate();

        }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

       e.printStackTrace();
    }



}
}
```

the output is

got connection
  6

but the changes are no reflected :(

Comment: Replace `System.out.println("exception")` with `e.printStackTrace()`, and then tell us what it says.

Comment: You might want too look at http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/

Comment: You still need to *tell us what it says*. Show us the stack trace that it prints to the console.

Comment: there is no stack trace.it runs perfectly. even when i make it 
int rows=ps.executeUpdate(); it shows the value of row to be 1 but when i look at the table , there is no sign of the record.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to INSERT a new UID with the current MAX(UID). I imagine UID is the Primary Key, thus requiring uniqueness. Either add one to id during the insert (also using WhiteFang34's suggestion), use a sequence, or some other mechanism for autoupdating the column (autonumber in MySQL for instance).

Comment: i did increment id , the program executes but the changes are not visible in the table :(

Comment: @Arora Does that mean that after incrementing the id, before inserting (which is not going to be thread safe, but probably will work in small sample projects), it executes _without_ printing "exception" or that it simply does not crash?

Comment: after incrementing the id, it prints executes but the changes are not reflected in the table

Comment: If it claims to be executing (and therefore claims to actually insert 1 record; `rows == 1`), then I can only assume that you have a transactional view of your table. Reload the table.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're reading `UID` as an `int`, you might need to set it as one too. You also likely need to increase it by one since you're currently using the `max(UID)` that already exists.

```
ps.setInt(1, id + 1);
```

Or perhaps you don't need to specify it at all because it's an auto-incrementing column?

Comment: but i did convert it into string.?

Comment: You should specify more of the details like the exception stack trace as skaffman suggested. Otherwise we can only guess what your problem is.